# Excel VBA Named Range Scope and/or Permanence of a Named Range

Tags: excel, vba, scope, named-ranges

The Sub shown below is in the workbook's Module1 (in the Modules folder)

The workbook/file is named `"240122 Range Name Scope v01.xlsm"`
It has 2 worksheets `S1` and `S2`.
Each worksheet has One Named Range.

Running this macro places
in the cell Worksheets("S1").Cells(1,2)
(the above being cell B1 in worksheet  S1)
the following text:  =SUM(r_IN_Wksht_S2)

HOWEVER THE RETURNED VALUE IS    `#NAME?`
which I assume means Excel doesn't know the Named Range  `r_IN_Wksht_S2`

Can someone please help me understand why the value isn't 10?
The value of cell A1 in worksheet S2 is 10.

THE SUBROUTINE'S CODE:

```
Sub Scope_Rng_Name_In_2_Wkshts_Insert_Formula()

Dim r_IN_Wksht_S1 As Range 'Named Range in Worksheet S1
Dim r_IN_Wksht_S2 As Range 'Named Range in Worksheet S2

Set r_IN_Wksht_S1 = Worksheets("S1").Range("$A$1")
Set r_IN_Wksht_S2 = Worksheets("S2").Range("$A$1")

r_IN_Wksht_S1.Value = 5
r_IN_Wksht_S2.Value = 10

Worksheets("S1").Cells(1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(r_IN_Wksht_S2)"

End Sub
```

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:
I have looked for the named ranges   r_IN_Wksht_S1   and  r_IN_Wksht_S2   in Excel in the Name Manager function/area of the Formlas tab and those named ranges don't appear.

If I create the named ranges   r_IN_Wksht_S1   and  r_IN_Wksht_S2    with Workbook scope with the Name Manager function in the Formulas tab rather than creating the named ranges in Excel VBA the when I write the formula in Excel VBA:

`Worksheets("S1").Cells(1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(r_IN_Wksht_S2)"`

It works.  But I really need to be able to define/set the Named Ranges in VBA.

Comment: when you create variables in VBA such as `Dim r_IN_Wksht_S1  as Range` that is a variable in your VBA subroutine - it is NOT a named range in the worksheet.

Comment: can I create a named range in a workbook (I think I want to do it in the workbook, not the worksheet?)   with VBA code?

Comment: For example, see here on creating defined names / named ranges: https://softwarekeep.com/blog/vba-named-ranges-in-excel Note the difference between a name that has workbook scope (added to the worksheets), vs a name that has workbook scope (added to the workbook). I think its easier to just always use workbook scope, and all your names are unique names .... unless you really have a reason to want to have ranges with the same name on more than one worksheet. If you only want workbook-scoped names, that is mostly what you find when you google *vba created named range* - examples abound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of adding the statements to create a named range with *workbook scope* (the names must be unique within the workbook):

```
Sub Scope_Rng_Name_In_2_Wkshts_Insert_Formula()

Dim r_IN_Wksht_S1 As Range 'Named Range in Worksheet S1
Dim r_IN_Wksht_S2 As Range 'Named Range in Worksheet S2

Set r_IN_Wksht_S1 = Worksheets("S1").Range("$A$1")
Set r_IN_Wksht_S2 = Worksheets("S2").Range("$A$1")

r_IN_Wksht_S1.Value = 5
r_IN_Wksht_S2.Value = 10

'// Create Named Ranges
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="r_IN_Wksht_S1", RefersTo:=r_IN_Wksht_S1
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="r_IN_Wksht_S2", RefersTo:=r_IN_Wksht_S2

'//Or Alternative way to create named ranges
'r_IN_Wksht_S1.Name = "r_IN_Wksht_S1"
'r_IN_Wksht_S2.Name = "r_IN_Wksht_S2"

Worksheets("S1").Cells(1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(r_IN_Wksht_S2)"

End Sub
```

For further reference I have often used this site for details:
http://cpearson.com/Excel/DefinedNames.aspx

Also just as a tip, avoid very short one, two, or three letter names followed by numbers! For instance, `DCA1001` is not a good name for a named range because it is already the name of a cell in an excel spreadsheet - all the cells from `A1` to `XFD1048576` are already named cells in xlsx workbooks.

Comment: Thank you very much topsail.

'following works

Set rCellsA = Worksheets("S1").Range("a1")

'following don't.  Why?
Set rCellsA = Worksheets("S1").Range(Cells(2, 3))


Where can I learn to put carriage returns etc in comments?

Comment: You cannot put carriage returns in comments ;) `Range("A1")` works because it does. `Range(Cells(2,3))` doesn't because it doesn't. In the latter case it's also unnecessary. `Cells(2,3)` is all you need. But you can use two Cells to define a larger range with start and end cells so to speak: `Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(10, 10))` ... If you think about it, you *could* make it work with `Range(Cells(2,3), Cells(2,3))` but that is still unnecessary since `Cells(2,3)` by itself is enough. It takes time to get used to the syntax. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)

Comment: Thanks, @topsail!   I really appreciate your Excellent help.  I noticed, I think, you edited my initial post/question.  Can you direct me to info about how posts to stackoverflow should be properly formatted and submitted?   Thank you again for your help.  mtnmanmike

Comment: Sure there is an article here on formatting questions and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting